# Java11+Hibernate:Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Java and Hibernate. I was trying a simple example with a User details class, main class and `Hibernate.cfg.xml`. Running the application, I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)

I added `--add-modules java.xml.bind` in arguments, but now I am facing:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

I am using Java 11.

Comment: In Java 11 you also need to include the dependency. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/636009